# Prove that it is transitive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, relations

Below is what I have so far. I'm pretty sure that it is transitive, but I'm not sure how to prove that it is. Prove that A is or isn't transitive.

[image]

Comment: What do you mean by $0 \not\in a$?

Comment: I stated a cannot be 0 because in my argument I say 0=0/a and if a was 0, it would be undefined.. Correct?

Comment: You just want to see that $0$ is rational. To do that, write $0 = 0/1$, for example. Most people would accept the fact that $0$ is rational as known anyway.

Comment: You should write "the definition of *the* relation" - the relation has already been identified by the time you write that. Why do you write "Suppose $y - x = -a$"?

Comment: Hmm, yeah it would make more sense if instead of suppose, I write since.

Comment: Actually, then would be better than since

Comment: Right. You already did the supposing when you wrote $x - y = a$. $y - x = - a$ is a consequence of that. You don't need to suppose it. After that, it's not because "$x \sim y$ and $y \sim x$" that $\sim$ is symmetric. It's because *whenever* $x \sim y$, you have $y \sim x$. Also, once you've said that, it's no longer "by the definition of" the relation. For transitivity, see Aram's answer.

Comment: Great, thank you for your input!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x-y$ is rational and $y-z$ is rational, then its sum its rational, but this is $$x-y + y -z = x-z$$